# Как убрать выделение checkbox в соседнем компоненте?

Tags: typescript, angular

Есть у меня основной компонент, в котором лежит два компонента:
headerTable, rowTable. 
В headerTable у меня именования колонок таблицы и есть чексбокс, который при checked выделяет все строки в rowTable (и наоборот). В rowTable тоже есть checkbox (как раз этот чексбокс и выделятся для выбора строки).
Я хочу сделать следующий сценарий:

1. Нажать на выделение всех строк (в headerTable нажать на чексбокс), и
   убрать из выделения какую-нибудь из строк.
2. После того, как уберу чексбокс в какой-нибудь строке, в headerTable чексбокс должен убраться.

Я пытался это сделать посредством декоратора Input, но, видимо, тк разные контексты, то и инпут не срабатывает.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'headerTable',
  template: '<input type="checkbox" [ngModel]="allItems" (ngModelChange)=onChange($event)>'
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  @Input() allItems: boolean;
  onChange(flag: boolean) {
    this.allItems = flag;
  }
}
...
@Component({
  selector: 'row',
  template: '<input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)">'
})
export class RowComponent {
  @Output() checkedItem = new EventEmitter<number>();
  onChange(flag: boolean) {
    this.checkedItem.emit(5);
  }
}
...
```

page.html:

```
<headerTable [allItems]="allItems"></headerTable>
<row (checkedItem)="checkedItem($event)"></row>
```

page.ts:

```
  checkedItem(id: number) {
    this.allItems = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне немного тяжело разобраться в вопросе, обладая ограниченным количеством информации. Но я так понял из вопроса, что вы пытаетесь заставить коммуницировать 2 компонента, находящиеся на 1 уровне через родителя:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот именно в такие моменты приходят на помощь сервисы-состояния, потому что обычную коммуникацию намного тяжелее оддебажить. На вашем месте я б создал такой сервис:

```
@Injectable()
export class TableService implements OnDestroy {
  public allItemsSelected$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.allItemsSelected$.complete();
  }

  public setAllItemsSelectedTo(selected: boolean): void {
    this.allItemsSelected$.next(selected);
  }
}
```

Далее добавил бы сервис в провайдеры родительского компонента, который находится сверху `app-table-row` и `app-table-header`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  viewProviders: [TableService]
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(private tableService: TableService) {}

  public get allItemsSelected$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.tableService.allItemsSelected$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

В шаблоне компонента мы уже исключаем коммуницирование через обычные переменные:

```
<app-table-header [allItems]="allItemsSelected$ | async"></app-table-header>
```

В методе, который слушает событие `ngModelChange` мы также заменяем переменную на генерирование события:

```
constructor(private tableService: TableService) {}

public onChange(selected: boolean): void {
  this.tableService.setAllItemsSelectedTo(selected);
}
```

Точно также инжектим этот сервис в компонент `app-table-row` и при клике на чекбокс - если значение событие равняется `false`, то генерируем событие для `app-table-header`, это решение вашего второго вопроса:

> После того, как уберу чексбокс в какой-нибудь строке, в headerTable чексбокс должен убраться.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table-row'
})
export class TableRowComponent {
  constructor(private tableService: TableService) {}

  public onChange(selected: boolean): void {
    if (selected) {
      return;
    }

    this.tableService.setAllItemsSelectedTo(selected);
  }
}
```

P.S. - генерировать событие `checkedItem` уже не нужно.

Comment: Спасибо, про сервис была идея, но не избыточно ли это всё для одной малой логики - убрать чекбокс?

Comment: а в чем избыточность? взамен спаггети с одной переменной и аутпутами вы получаете тотальный контроль над бизнес логикой, к тому же Мишко не зря придумал сервисы (они ж ведь не для дураков)? :)